# How to find the connected WIFI MacAddress in Android 9 Programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, ip-address, mac-address

Android documentation [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#version_specific_details_identifiers_in_m)

> MAC addresses are globally unique, not user-resettable, and survive
> factory resets. For these reasons, to protect user privacy, on Android
> versions 6 and higher, access to MAC addresses is restricted to system
> apps. Third-party apps can't access them

But this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilyas.ilyasapps.wifidistancestrength&hl=en&gl=US) on the play store shows the Wifi MacAddress.

I'm working on a project which involves the finding of connected WIFI Mac addresses and I've tried almost every solution available on StackOverflow but none of them is working.

**If the above mention app can access the wifi mac address then we can too but how?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android 10 and i use this code below :

```
fun getMacAddress(): String {
    try {
        val all: List<NetworkInterface> = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
        for (networkInterface in all) {
            if (!networkInterface.name.equals("wlan0", true)) continue
            val macBytes = networkInterface.hardwareAddress ?: return ""
            val res1 = StringBuilder()
            for (b in macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b))
            }
            if (res1.isNotEmpty()) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length - 1)
            }
            return res1.toString()
        }
    } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "getMacAddress: ", ex)
    }
    return ""
}
```

I hope this will help you !